# Simple htaccess redirect extension .php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, directory

I'm trying to perform this task for my server, but I could not realize how to do it.
I need to redirect any url to url.php. For example, to redirect domain.com/about to domain.com\about.php.

I've always used this code, that's working fine for me:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

The problem is that I need to do the same for domain.com/api/. In the API folder.
I tried changing the script and adding other similar line but it's not working as it should.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `RewriteBase /` to `RewriteBase /api/` and everything should be fine (api/about.php etc are called out)

Comment: Thank you very much my friend. I didn't realize that was the problem. Thank you !!!